# Deleting json block using jq

Tags: json, key, jq

I want to remove an entire JSON block by providing specific value to JQ.

JSON block:

```
{
  "deployed": false,
  "identifier": "agent_credentials",
  "value": 
{
  "identity": "vcap",
  password": ""
   }
 },
```

And I want to remove it by providing value "agent_credentials" to JQ.

I am trying `del(..|.agent_credentials)` but it doesn't clear the block.

Comment: edit your question with a final expected result and extend the initial json fragment with more objects

Answer (score 0):

Here’s one way:

```
with_entries( if .value|(type=="object" and .identifier == "agent_credentials")
              then empty else . end)
```